# How to create IE browser helper objects to respond to specific MIME file type(e.g. .helloword file)?

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, browser, helper

When IE encounter .PDF file, it will open Adobe PDF Reader within IE and user can read the PDF content.

What I want to do is to make IE to behavior the same, but with my own MIME type, let say .helloworld file extension.

So, is that I have to do the following things:

1. Create a IE browser helper objects for IE to respond to specific MIME type (.helloworld)
2. Register/install the plugin in the registry system
3. Create a program to be called by IE.

That's all?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols and MIME type filters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767916(v=vs.85).aspx#Creating_a_Pluggable